# How can I see the SQL generated by Sequelize.js?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I want to see the SQL commands that are sent to the PostgreSQL server because I need to check if they are correct. In particular, I am interested in the table creation commands.

For instance, ActiveRecord (Ruby) prints its SQL statements to standard output. Is this possible with Node.js/ActionHero.js and Sequelize.js as well?

Answer (score 224, accepted):

You can pass a logging option when initializing sequelize, which can either be a function or console.log

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
    logging: console.log
    logging: function (str) {
        // do your own logging
    }
});
```

You can also pass a logging option to .sync if you only want to view the table creation queries

```
sequelize.sync({ logging: console.log })
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I want. `DEPRECATION WARNING: The logging-option should be either a function or false. Default: console.log` -- what does this mean?

Comment: Means you should pass a function instead of true.

Comment: I never ever passed `true`.

Comment: I'm a bit late to the party, but `console.log` works in mysterious ways. You should be able to avoid the log message using `{ logging: (msg) => console.log(msg) }` or `{ logging: function(msg) { console.log(msg) } }`. (untested so I could be totally wrong)

Comment: Is there any way I can see the generated query , but the query should not execute ?

Answer (score 80):

As stated in the log `Error: Please note that find* was refactored and uses only one options object from now on.`. For the latest sequelize version (4) if you want to have the result for only one command:

`User.findAll({where: {...}, logging: console.log})`

Comment: this also works with native queries: `query(statement, {
      replacements: {
        userId: userId,
        superiorPositions: [ 4, 5, 7 ],
        departments: [ departmentId ]
      },
      logging: console.log
    });`

Comment: this is the correct answer for where logging: console.log should be placed, in sequelize 4.

Comment: `logging: console.log`  > top thanks!

Comment: Better one if you need to debug just selected queries! Thank you!

Answer (score 33):

If you want to look at the sequelize for one command you can listen to it and attach a function to the print the sql.

Check out this example:

```
User.find(1).on('sql', console.log).then(function(user) {
  // do whatever you want with the user here
```

Comment: You now pass in a logger as an option to log a single statement: `User.find(1, { logging: console.log })`

Comment: Mine just says `<functionName>.findOne(...).on is not a function`

Using sequelize 3.30.4

Comment: It appears that some of the association mixins do not support the logging option. Specifically, the `get*` on the source of a belongsTo relationship.

Answer (score 29):

You can also take advantage of Sequelize's use of the Debug module, by setting your environment, thus:
`DEBUG=sequelize:sql*`
before starting your app.

Comment: this should be an answer!  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: how do you disable this? I put this in my env and now it's impossible to remove it after debug.

Comment: @guest - just redefine the DEBUG variable as nothing. `DEBUG=''`