# Value to place inside a WHERE clause in Sequelize, PostgreSQL to get everything

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have this piece of code:

```
return User.findAll({where: {}, include:[
  {model: UserInfo, where: {
    gender: genderPreference
  }}
]
```

I want to pass such a value in genderPreference so that it gives me all the values. Currently I'm passing either "Male" or "Female" which gives me that data from database accordingly; but if there is no preference for any of the genders then i have no idea on what to do. 
I have tried null, " " , "" ; but none of them work. Is there any solution to this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually solved this with a different approach. Placing:

```
gender: null
```

actually searches if the gender field in the database is null or not, so I had to solve it with a different approach. I wanted "all the data" in the database. 
So, this pretty much solved it:

```
 if(req.body.genderPreference == "none"){
    conditionalUserInfo = {model: UserInfo, where:{}};
} else {
    conditionalUserInfo = {model: UserInfo, where: {gender: req.body.genderPreference}};
}
return User.findAll({where: {}, include:[
  conditionalUserInfo
]
```

GenderPreference parameter contains either 'Male' or 'Female' or 'none'.

Answer (score 1):

There's a much better way to achieve what you need here without the if/else clause

```
return User.findAll({where: {}, include:[
 {
    model: UserInfo,
    where: req.body.genderPreference ? { gender: req.body.genderPreference } : {}
  }
]
```

This allows the database search if the body is present, and returns all gender preference if the body isn't present. I believe this is a much cleaner code.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use quotes on `null`, it'll work fine

```
return User.findAll({where: {}, include:[
  {model: UserInfo, where: {
    gender: null
  }}
]
```

See [the tutorial for more information](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html)

Comment: Hey Evan, thanks for trying but just placing null didn't fix the problem. I still get no data from the database even after putting gender as null. I guess the database tries to match the null value we put in as well.

Comment: not likely, turn out statement logging and check what your sequelize is sending to the database. You can use sequelize https://stackoverflow.com/a/21431627/124486 or postgresql's log_min_statement

Comment: `SELECT "User"."id","User"."email"...(other sql here)........INNER JOIN "UserInfos" AS "UserInfo" ON "User"."id" = "UserInfo"."userId" AND "UserInfo"."gender" IS NULL;` I get this as my sql. Is there anything wrong with it?