# How can I ONLY see the SQL generated by Sequelize.js?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I want to view the SQL like below, but WITHOUT executing.
[How can I see the SQL generated by Sequelize.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21427501/how-can-i-see-the-sql-generated-by-sequelize-js)

*Note: Question is clearly different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I see the SQL generated by Sequelize.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21427501/how-can-i-see-the-sql-generated-by-sequelize-js)

Comment: The question may be similar but it is CLEARLY different. If I have somehow missed the answer in the the related page please use a comment. When did Stackexchange become a bureaucratic institution.

Comment: @DamienGolding As far as I know, Sequelize does not offer a way to _preview_ the SQL statement of an ORM method. It does allow you to see the generated SQL after an ORM method has finished through the `logging` prop in the DB config. (More info https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2325)

Comment: @mcranston18 Thanks. Seems like that link wants what I am looking for but is yet to be made fully.