# Log query result of sequelize.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I need to log RAW query generated by Sequelize and it's result to get the ID.
RAW query of sequelize with insert ID as default, but I want to know that ID.

Loggin: function(str) solve logging raw query but not help me see it's id.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I see the SQL generated by Sequelize.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21427501/how-can-i-see-the-sql-generated-by-sequelize-js)

Comment: @Rastalamm yep. Logging: function(str) anyway help me log raw query, but not result of query

Comment: You want to log out the results of an insert? Can you paste some code on how you are calling your insert?

Comment: @Rastalamm yea but there is a big project and I can't add code in thousand route. But I solved the problem by configure Sequelize's code. Thanks for ur support