# findAndCountAll count gets a bigger number than the actual returned data

Tags: sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize `findAndCountAll()` for my website's pagination.

The `findAndCountAll()` returns the total items number(`3990`) is bigger than the actual returned data number (`3770`).

Does anyone know how to make the `findAndCountAll()` returns the total items number which is the same as the actual data returned?

The table which I use `findAndCountAll()` queries including two other tables, like the code below:

```js
const patientModel: IIncludeOptions = {
    model: Patient,
    attributes: ["deviceId", "firstName", "lastName"],
};

const deviceModel: IIncludeOptions = {
    model: Device,
    required: true,
    attributes: ["deviceId", "deviceSerialNumber"],
    include: [patientModel],
};

const eventCodeModel: IIncludeOptions = {
    model: EventCode,
    required: true,
    attributes: ["name"],
};

const opts: IFindOptions = {
    ...pageSizeLimit,
    offset : offsetNum,
    attributes: ["id", "deviceId", "eventId", "dispatchedAt", "message", "createdAt"],
    include: [
        deviceModel,
        eventCodeModel,
    ],
    order: sortBy,
};

const resCount = await DeviceEvent.findAndCountAll(opts).then((response) => {
    const totalItems = response.count;
    return {
        totalItems,
        currentPage: page || 1,
    };
});
```

Comment: How are you counting "the actual returned data number (3770)" ?

Comment: @Emma findAndCountAll() method returns an array which contains all the data being fetched from database, the array's length reflects the actual returned data number.

Comment: If I read correctly, you need `distinct: true` in `opts`, this will count the number of `DeviceEvent` itself (array length). 

`findAndCountAll()` counts the # of records that is fetched which means if you have `include`, it will count the number of records with joined objects.

Answer (score 9):

What worked for me is adding `distinct: true` to the query. Without this Sequelize returns the count for the values without an inner join/required: true.

```
const posts = Post.findAndCountAll({
    include: ['attachment', 'users', 'x count of models'],
    distinct: true
});
```

In the code used in the question, this would be:

```
const opts: IFindOptions = {
    ...pageSizeLimit,
    offset : offsetNum,
    attributes: ["id", "deviceId", "eventId", "dispatchedAt", "message", "createdAt"],
    include: [
        deviceModel,
        eventCodeModel,
    ],
    order: sortBy,
    distinct: true,
};
```

Details for this are mentioned here - [Count issue in findandCountAll](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/9481)

Comment: Works. You rock. This was driving me nuts. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set separate: true in your option when you have one-to-many associations, for example :

```
users.findAndCountAll({
include:[{model:messages,as:"messages",separate:true}]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your SQL logging the query.

Follow those instructions to get the query dump: [How can I see the SQL generated by Sequelize.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21427501/how-can-i-see-the-sql-generated-by-sequelize-js)

And see if the count number is the same that `findAndCountAll()` returns to you.

Maybe the way that `sequelize.js` mounts the query affects the results.

Answer (score 0):

Sequelize is performing two queries for findAndCountAll—one for performing the original query and another for counting the records.
There are two problems with this method:

- First is that sequelize performing unnecessary joins for counting the records. You don't need to do those joins.
- Also in some cases, these extra joins cause sequelize to return a wrong number of records as a count. In my case count was 26 instead of 4.

Using distinct=true solves the problem in some cases. But the problem remains the same in another case and causes the wrong number to be returned as a count.

I came up with a solution by creating my method.
One for performing the origin query and another for counting records.

```
import { Attributes, FindAndCountOptions, ModelStatic } from 'sequelize';
import { Model } from 'sequelize-typescript';

Using nest js and sequelize-typescript
/**
 * This is a workaround for the issue
 * sequlize do an extra join for counting the number of records.
 * This is a problem when you have a lot of records and you want to count them
 * also in some cases sequelize returns a WRONG number of records which is another problem
 * for the method findAndCountAll sequelize do two queries. one for counting and one for getting the records
 * Here I added a new method findAndCountAllCorrectly which does the same thing but without extra joins and also in the correct way
 * *IMPORTANT: instead of using findAndCountAll use findAndCountAllCorrectly. For this, you need to extend
 * *your model from CustomModel instead of Model
 */

export class CustomModel<T> extends Model<T> {
  public static async findAndCountAllCorrectly<M extends Model>(
    this: ModelStatic<M>,
    options?: Omit<FindAndCountOptions<Attributes<M>>, 'group'>,
  ): Promise<{ rows: M[]; count: number }> {
    const itemsPromise = super.findAll<M>(options);
    const countPromise = super.count({ where: options?.where });
    console.log(
      'hi im going the count all records without extra joins and most importantly in a correct way',
    );
    const [items, count] = await Promise.all([itemsPromise, countPromise]);
    // const count = countGroup[0].count;
    return { rows: items, count };
  }
}
```