# Sequelize Op.iLike throwing Error with MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, sequelize.js

`Error: Invalid value { undefined: 'w%' }`

This is my query:

```
  results = await models.Record.findAll({
          where: {
            
            name: {
              [Op.iLike]: prefix + "%", //causing problems
            },
          },
          order: [["createdAt", "DESC"]],
          limit: num,
        });
```

name is a String field in my MySQL table.

You have an error in your SQL syntax near `'ILIKE' 'james'`. It seems the ORM converts the query to ILIKE, which is not valid.

Comment: I suggest that you log the final SQL query. It's tough to debug generated code by staring at code that generates it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21427501/how-can-i-see-the-sql-generated-by-sequelize-js/26171518

Comment: ^ you can do that buy adding `log: true` to your query which will print the SQL to the console.

Comment: Sequelize ILIKE is for postgres only.  MySQL doesn't support ILIKE. Instead, the regular LIKE in MySQL is case insensitive search by default.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case-sensitivity.html

Comment: Sequelize doesn't have LIKE.

Comment: They actually do. `[Op.like]: prefix + '%'`   yet, if you are searching by `prefix`, you can use `Op.startsWith` as well.  It internally translates into LIKE statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sequelize should work with ILike for mysql see link at the end

you ca use instead `Op.startsWith`

```
    results = await models.Record.findAll({
      where: {
        
        name: {
          [Op.startsWith]: prefix, 
        },
      },
      order: [["createdAt", "DESC"]],
      limit: num,
    });
```

Further string functions see [manual](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html)

```
  [Op.like]: '%hat',                       // LIKE '%hat'
  [Op.notLike]: '%hat',                    // NOT LIKE '%hat'
  [Op.startsWith]: 'hat',                  // LIKE 'hat%'
  [Op.endsWith]: 'hat',                    // LIKE '%hat'
  [Op.substring]: 'hat',                   // LIKE '%hat%'
  [Op.iLike]: '%hat',                      // ILIKE '%hat' (case insensitive) (PG only)
  [Op.notILike]: '%hat',                   // NOT ILIKE '%hat'  (PG only)
  [Op.regexp]: '^[h|a|t]',                 // REGEXP/~ '^[h|a|t]' (MySQL/PG only)
  [Op.notRegexp]: '^[h|a|t]',              // NOT REGEXP/!~ '^[h|a|t]' (MySQL/PG only)
  [Op.iRegexp]: '^[h|a|t]',                // ~* '^[h|a|t]' (PG only)
  [Op.notIRegexp]: '^[h|a|t]',             // !~* '^[h|a|t]' (PG only)
```

Comment: Thanks. Frustrating that the platform specific operations aren't detailed in the API docs.