Sequelize many-to-many relation query search very slow
I use nodejs, mysql and sequelize. I have 3 model: Post , Tags and PostToTags. I add many-to-many relation between Post and Tags.  Post model have title, content attributes. Tags model have title and description attribute. my relation:
 Posts.belongsToMany(models.Tags, {
        through: models.PostToTags, // Junction table
        foreignKey: 'postId',
        otherKey: 'tagId',
        as: 'tags',
      });

after i generate 10000 data.
after i have route: inside i get data:
const options = {
    where: {},
    order: [['date', 'desc']],
    include: [ 'tags'],
    offset: (page - 1) * limit,
    limit: parseInt(limit, 10),
    distinct: true,
  };
const { count, rows } = await Posts.findAndCountAll(options);

but this take many times. problem here when get tags. Data must be more 10000. how to do this work fast? I dont have any idea. Please help me.

Retrieve the generated sql statements and run explain on them and see what that turns up.

I dont understand. what i do need?

Sequelize generates sql statements under the hood. You need to retrieve those first.

how to do this?

Please search before asking a question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21427501/how-can-i-see-the-sql-generated-by-sequelize-js
